# What happens to quarter valve when I don't turn it on/off completely?

Tags: plumbing, hvac, valve, humidifier

I have a quarter valve for the supply line to my whole house humidifier (fan-powered, by-pass type). It is on when pointing up (i.e. 12 o'clock) position and off when pointing to the right (i.e. 3 o'clock). If I put it in between, say 1 o'clock or 2 o'clock, will I be able to control the valve opening size and thus the flow rate? More precisely,

Question 1: Does a quarter valve's opening depend on the angle in a proportional way? Or you have to turn it to almost complete "on" in order for it to be on?

Question 2: Since a humidifier itself does not have a flow control, shall I control the flow using the valve in order to save water?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quarter-turn valve is a poor choice for metering (controlling the flow, as you want to.) They are best for "on/off" operation but plenty of folks use them for flow control anyway.

The valve is literally a ball with a hole drilled through it, when closed the hole is at 90 degrees to the flow in the pipe and not exposed at all, when open the hole is in line with the pipe and flow is unrestricted. Between those points the hole is partially exposed at both ends, somewhat like the phases of the moon. Depending on flow rate the sharp edges of the hole in the ball being in the stream can cause noisy flow, and the reduction or increase in flow is not linear with movement of the handle (so a movement of the same amount in one position might cause a much different change in flow than the same movement at a different position.)

A system designed for best operating control would have a quarter-turn ball valve for shutoff and a metering valve for metering. That is somewhat more expensive than using the one valve for both purposes.

Comment: As answered , they are not control valves; partial opening may promote deterioration of the seals.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Yes, as you note, people have reported leaving quarter turn valves partly open can make them fail to completely shut off afterward.